# PHP-ZMQ pecl installation error - Unable to find libzmq installation

Tags: centos, php, yum, queue

I've run below shell command as per ZeroMQ website to install PHP-ZMQ:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.zero.mq
sudo pecl install pear.zero.mq/zmq-beta
```

Below are traces for the installation:

```
downloading zmq-1.0.6.tgz ...
Starting to download zmq-1.0.6.tgz (23,880 bytes)
........done: 23,880 bytes
10 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootwCcLwT/zmq-1.0.6
running: /var/tmp/zmq/configure
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable 0MQ support... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking libzmq installation... configure: error: Unable to find libzmq installation
ERROR: `/var/tmp/zmq/configure' failed
```

I already have `libzmq` installed via `Yum` in my `CentOS 5` server.

I can also confirm by running below

```
yum install zeromq
```

and traces below:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.site.net.au
 * extras: mirror.site.net.au
 * updates: mirror.site.net.au
Setting up Install Process
Package zeromq-3.2.2-13.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package zeromq-3.2.2-13.1.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So I have `libzmq` installed so I don't see why `PHP-ZMQ` is throwing error at the installation.

What would be the cause for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the development files. I'd wager they're called zeromq-devel or something of that sort on RPM based distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Installing CZMQ via brew solved this for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer, _e.g._ describing what CZMQ is and how installing that can fix/address the OP's issue?

Answer (score 1):

For any future guy with this trouble - 
I did try this as instructed from this [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php) - `sudo pecl install zmq-beta` in my Mac. Then I did try as instructed by @Tinus Guichelaar - `brew install czmq`. It worked after lots of failed solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues, installing ZMQ on Centos 7 with PHP 7.1.3
Installing through PECL failed, building from source, same issue.

This solved it for me:

```
yum search zmq
```

You will get a list of all available packages, choose the one that fits your specific setup (in my case this was the result:)

```
=========================================================== N/S matched:    zmq ============================================================
cppzmq-devel.x86_64 : Development files for cppzmq
czmq-devel.x86_64 : Development files for the czmq package
perl-ZMQ-Constants.noarch : Constants for the libzmq library
perl-ZMQ-LibZMQ3.x86_64 : Perl wrapper for the libzmq 3.x library
python-zmq-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package python-zmq
czmq.x86_64 : High-level C binding for 0MQ (ZeroMQ)
php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php54-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php55-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php56-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php70-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php71-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php72-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php73-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php74-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php80-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
php81-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 : ZeroMQ messaging
python-txzmq.noarch : Twisted bindings for ZeroMQ
python-zmq.x86_64 : Software library for fast, message-based applications
python-zmq-tests.x86_64 : Software library for fast, message-based applications
python2-zmq.x86_64 : Software library for fast, message-based applications
python2-zmq-tests.x86_64 : Software library for fast, message-based applications
python36-zmq.x86_64 : Software library for fast, message-based applications
python36-zmq-tests.x86_64 : Software library for fast, message-based applications

Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

I picked the PHP71 version, as that would fit my needs (could be different in your situation)

```
yum install php71-php-pecl-zmq.x86_64 -y
```

Done!